# image drive with safecopy and compress the output

Tags: compression, disk-image

I am trying to image a drive with SafeCopy and compress the output file on the fly so that it won't take up way too much space. (aka 500GB > 50GB)

Will this command work?

> sudo safecopy --stage1 /dev/source | pigz -9 /media/mount/dest.img.gz

Or am I missing something?

1. safecopy = image software
2. pigz = multi-threaded gzip

Comment: I tried to safecopy a user's home, which takes 400 GB on the drive, but the image is 900GB and now it failed due to no space left on a device. What is going on, why is the image so large?

Comment: safecopy copies all data sectors including empty space, thats the reason why its so big, and why i asked this other question about compression ;)

Comment: Right, I described my problem wrong. I would deal with same problem as you provided I was able to create the image. What I don't understand and I couldn't even find any info about it is why the image took over 900 GB and failed due to not enough space left on a new 1TB drive, while the whole faulty disk had only 500GB and the partition I was trying to recover had only 400GB.